# How to modify text file's substring using php?

Tags: php

This is text file's data (Presidents.txt):

```
George Washington 
John Adams
George Jefferson
James Madison
```

I want to replace **George** [3rd line] to **Thomas** without deleting or replacing all data of the text file. I want to delete or replace only  **George** from the third line.

This is the code that I am trying:

```
$file = fopen("Presidents.txt","r+");
fwrite($file,'Thomas');
```

But output:

```
Thomas Washington 
John Adams
George Jefferson
James Madison
```

But my desired output is:

```
George Washington 
John Adams
Thomas Jefferson
James Madison
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is it a requirement that only "George" is used as identifier? I mean, is it okay to search for "George Jefferson" instead of just George?

Comment: No, it is not only for "George". Text file is big. All other data is to be exist during editing. So, in this case fopen("filename","w") is not working because it is creating a new file deleting all other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $file= "Presidents.txt";
    $lines = file($file);

    $lines[2] = str_replace("George", "Thomas", $lines[2]);
    file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $lines) );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You thinking about this?

```
$handle = fopen("Presidents.txt", "r");
$file="";
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
        if($line=="George Jefferson\r\n") {
            $line="Thomas Jefferson\r\n";
        }
    $file .= $line;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
$handle = fopen("Presidents.txt", "w+");
fwrite($handle,$file);
fclose($handle);
```